# Get a list of all files with .md5 counterparts in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a PowerShell script in which I need to get a list of files that have complementary .md5 files. For example, if I have a file name `abc.txt` I only want to add it to the list if there exists a file named `abc.txt.md5` in the same directory.

This is my attempt, but it's not working. I'm not sure why?

```
$DirectoryToScan = ".\SomePath"
$Files = Get-ChildItem $DirectoryToScan -Recurse |
    Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer } |
    Where-Object { $_.Name -notmatch ".*\.md5" } |
    Where-Object { Test-Path "$($_.FullName).md5" }
```

It works fine without the last `Where-Object` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you had give does work for me, but you can try doing something like this:

```
gci $DirectoryToScan -recurse -exclude "*.md5" | ?{ -not $_.PsIsContainer } | 
      ?{ test-path ($_.fullname + ".md5") }
```

Comment: Embarrassing... I may have just been running the script against a directory without any .md5 files. I like your script for its brevity.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work, and save you hitting the directory again for the test-path.

```
$DirectoryToScan = ".\SomePath"
$temp = Get-Childitem $DirectoryToScan -recurse | select -expand fullname 
$files = $temp |
foreach  {if ($_ -notmatch '\.md5$' -and $temp -contains "$_.md5"){$_}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-ChildItem $DirectoryToScan -Recurse | `
  Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and (Test-Path "$($_.FullName).md5" -PathType Leaf)}
```